# Convert one dimensional string array to two dimensional string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

```
char   *buffer;        /* holds the file contents. */
char   **transfer;
unsigned long    countNewLine = 0;
size_t  rowTrack;
size_t  columnTrack;

// assume countNewLine is 12

buffer_size = BUFSIZ;
buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
transfer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*sizeof(countNewLine));

columnTrack = 0;


while ( columnTrack < countNewLine ) {

    for ( rowTrack = 0; buffer[rowTrack] != '\n' || buffer[rowTrack] != '\0'; rowTrack++ )
        transfer[columnTrack][rowTrack] = buffer[rowTrack];

        columnTrack++;
}
```

I'm trying to convert 1D string array to 2D. I don't have any idea about my mistake. Thank you for solution.

Debugger result:

```
    buffer  char *  "first\nsecond\nthird\nfourth\nfifth\nsixth\nseventh\n
              eighth\nninth\ntenth\neleventh\ntwelfth\nthirteenth"  0x0000000100801200
    *buffer char    'f' 'f'
    countNewLine    unsigned long   12  12
    transfer    char ** 0x100105520 0x0000000100105520
    *transfer   char *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
    rowTrack    size_t  0   0
    columnTrack size_t  0   0
```

Comment: `sizeof(char*)*sizeof(countNewLine)`..looks suspicious.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: The loop will never terminate with `buffer[rowTrack] != '\n' || buffer[rowTrack] != '\0';` it should use `&&` and also, you have not allocated memory for each row of `*transfer[]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Desktop/test/test/test/main.c:14:13: Definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer for `char *transfer[]`

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to *split* string by newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. In this line

```
transfer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*sizeof(countNewLine));
```

the second `sizeof()` is incorrect, the line should be

```
transfer = malloc(sizeof(char*) * countNewLine);
```

Next, you did not allocate memory for each row, which could be something like this

```
for ( rowTrack = 0; rowTrack < countNewLine; rowTrack++)
    transfer[rowTrack] = malloc(BUFSIZ);    // or whatever the line length is
```

The `for` loop will never terminate by using `||`

```
for ( rowTrack = 0; buffer[rowTrack] != '\n' || buffer[rowTrack] != '\0'; rowTrack++ )
```

should be

```
for ( rowTrack = 0; buffer[rowTrack] != '\n' && buffer[rowTrack] != '\0'; rowTrack++ )
```

And lastly, I think you have your row and column indexing reversed in this statement:

```
transfer[columnTrack][rowTrack] = buffer[rowTrack];
```

There is a much cleaner way to split your string, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZ 512

int main(void) { 

    char *buffer;
    char *sptr;
    char **transfer = NULL;
    int rows = 0, row;

    /* ... load the file contents */
    buffer = malloc(BUFSIZ);
    strcpy (buffer, "first\nsecond\nthird\nfourth\nfifth\nsixth\nseventh\neighth\nninth\ntenth\neleventh\ntwelfth\nthirteenth");

    /* split the input */
    sptr = strtok(buffer, "\r\n");
    while (sptr) {
        transfer = realloc(transfer, (rows+1) * sizeof(char*));  // expand string array
        transfer[rows] = malloc(1+strlen(sptr));    // memory for string
        strcpy (transfer[rows], sptr);              // copy the token
        rows++;
        sptr = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
    }

    /* show array */
    printf ("Showing %d rows\n", rows);
    for (row=0; row<rows; row++) {
        printf ("%s\n", transfer[row]);
        free (transfer[row]);                       // release mem
    }

    free (transfer);                                // release mem
    free (buffer);                                  // release mem
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Showing 13 rows
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
sixth
seventh
eighth
ninth
tenth
eleventh
twelfth
thirteenth
```

Comment: The comma in the condition does not do what (I think) you expect it to do: `for (...; expr1, expr2; ...)`

Comment: `buffer = malloc(BUFSIZ);` or `transfer = malloc(BUFSIZ);` ?

Comment: @pmg I expect both expressions to be true for the loop to proceed, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3674483 `**transfer` is an array of pointers, equivalent to `*transfer[]`

Comment: no: `for (k = 0; 0, 1; k++)` is an infinite loop (unless there's a break inside): http://codepad.org/XNaniURQ

Comment: @pmg thank you, in that case I edited the answer to use `&&` instead of `,`